# Best Listview optimized design for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, android-listview

How can we display a listview which contains row items of a string of 40words nicely with good user experience or rather what layout would be best?

Comment: Try it out for yourself first and if you have questions we can help you.

Comment: I had tried already but the list row item looks very big and experience not right too book like

Answer (score 0):

you could try and use this library where the listview opens to a scroll view where you can display lots of words.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1624

Comment: How can I load an arraylist on the scroll view list, any documents on how to use the library